# DataReport - using page number?

Tags: vb6

I'm using DataReport-VB6 to generate my reports but I can't solve this problem.

Every page I print has its own number and it is sequencial and this number comes from a database. Not a problem with that.

Ex:
number saved on a database = 250
The problem is that if I generate a report with 2 pages the firts must be 251 e the second 252 and I don't know how to do that...

I thought about to use a label.caption with "%p" that brings the page number and sum to the number of my database but I couldn't.

Some idea?

Thanks in advanced and sorry for my english!

:P

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you can set the initial value of the page number because `%p` is intended to be used along with `%P` (Total Number of Pages), so they never provided an option to set the first page number to anything other than `1`.

If somebody else knows better I'd love to hear about it myself!

DataReports in VB6 were fairly basic, mainly to provide simple reporting while avoiding crowding out third party ISVs selling full-featured reporting tools.  The next *step up* was the "lite" version of Crystal Reports that shipped with VB6 Pro and Enterprise.